# How to Change Method for N Duration (Python)

Tags: python

I have a function that when called, modifies an existing method for N duration. How do I change the method back to the original method after N, while still only calling the function once?

My attempt:

```
def modifier(N, function):
    original_function = function
    while N:
        N = N - 1
        return modified(function)
    return original_function
```

Output that I want:

```
>>> function = modifier(2, function)
>>> function is modified(function)
    True
>>> function
>>> function is modified(function)
    True
>>> function
>>> function is modified(function)
    False
>>> function is original_function
    True
```

Other thoughts: I've considered using a generator and having

```
function = next(generator)
```

but I'm not sure if that's the correct approach.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the rationale behind changing a function?

Comment: What is `modified(function)`? You never defined `modified`

Comment: I want to change the function for a few calls, to refer to another function -- which modified does -- but change back afterwards.